# Horizontal scrolling controls volume (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, volume-control, libinput

I am on `Ubuntu 19.04`, `GNOME Shell 3.32.1`, on a Lenovo laptop. I have installed `libinput-tools` and some touchpad gestures work fine. However, there is a gesture that I cannot find in the libinput configuration file and I am not sure if it's from libinput (I also purged libinput and it still worked so I am almost sure it is not from libinput). When I scroll horizontal with two fingers, it controls the volume (scrolling right increases it while scrolling left decreases it).

It is very annoying and I am trying to find out how can I disable it. Any suggestions would be welcome!

**Edit:**
`synclient` output:

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1574
    RightEdge               = 5368
    TopEdge                 = 1350
    BottomEdge              = 4504
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 252
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = -114
    HorizScrollDelta        = -114
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0348797
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 1
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 28
    VertHysteresis          = 28
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3471
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 4100
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

**Edit2:** `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins | grep --ignore-case volume` output:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up 'XF86AudioRaiseVolume'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute 'XF86AudioMute'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down 'XF86AudioLowerVolume'
```

Comment: I do not remember. I have been using `libinput-tools` for a while. Again, even when I remove the package I still have that gesture, so it does not seem to be related.

Comment: Yes, just tried that. Also, [this](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) is the repository of `libinput` that I am using.

Comment: alright, here : https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md is where you can ask for help specific to that library. but since even after uninstall and rebbot your gestures still work I'm starting to think this library is not responsible.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's what I am saying :)

Comment: I don't think I have installed anything else related to the touchpad.

Comment: If you have any suggestions we could start from somewhere. I do not think I have installed anything else and if I knew I would probably be able to figure that out myself. I have spent a great amount of time searching for the cause before posting here..

Comment: What's the output to `synclient`?  Please [edit] your question to include this crucial info.

Comment: @Fabby I do not have `synclient` installed. Should I install it and post the output?

Comment: **jimouris** So confirmed not coming from mouse events.  (as you already suspected) Can you [edit] your question yet again and post the output to `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins | grep --ignore-case volume`  **CC @tatsu**